# Session in DB issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a web app where I use sessions to login. I started using this app on a shared hosting so I decided to move sessions into the db instead of using a shared folder (with all the security issues).

On my development server it is all running fine but on the new server I am setting up I cannot handle sessions data anymore ($_SESSION array remains empty).

The db has a simple structure: a session table with id,access and data;

The code to handle the sessions is the following **NOTE: I know that I am still using mysql_* api and it's deprecated** It's an old code I am porting to PDO (all the app is already working on PDO).

```
session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');

function _open(){
    global $_sess_db;
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = 'flipper';
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    if ($_sess_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)){ return mysql_select_db('jdev_db', $_sess_db); }
    return FALSE;
}

function _close(){
    global $_sess_db;
    return mysql_close($_sess_db);
}

function _read($id){
    global $_sess_db;
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = "SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = '$id'";
    if ($result = mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db)){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $record['data'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}

function _write($id, $data){   
    global $_sess_db;
    $access = time();
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $access = mysql_real_escape_string($access);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES ('$id', '$access', '$data')";
    return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}

function _destroy($id){
    global $_sess_db;
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE  id = '$id'";
    return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}

function _clean($max){
    global $_sess_db;
    $old = time() - $max;
    $old = mysql_real_escape_string($old);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE  access < '$old'";
    return mysql_query($sql, $_sess_db);
}
```

**In the DB when I load the login page it stores a new record with id and access only. When I login it doesn't write anything.**
How do I replace mysql_real_escape_string that is what I think is causing the error? Using PDO prepare?

Comment: *"How do I replace mysql_real_escape_string that is what I think is causing the error? Using PDO prepare?"* - You should use a prepared statement with PDO, `mysqli_` also has a prepared statement, just remember that you can't go mixing `mysql_` with anything other than its own API; same goes for the other two.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for confirming my guess. I moved straight from mysql_* to PDO (I don't use mysqli). So I'll update this code too. Thanks

Comment: prego Lelio. and you did include `session_start();` inside all files using sessions, correct?

Comment: Yes. This work on my development system without any issues. On the new server it doesn't store data but code is the same

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` if it's also a db error. I kind of think that that new server may be an issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Always the one with the error displays. I've missed you ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- error reporting is on in PHP.ini but cannot see anything... will check updating to PDO prepared statements if it fix